# Sub-menu closing when clicking on top of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap: Dropdown on Hover Plugin ( https://cameronspear.com/blog/bootstrap-dropdown-on-hover-plugin/ ) and it works perfectly. The problem is that I don't only have common sub-menus with just links. In a sub-menu I have a big login form where the user has to click some input boxes. My problem is that my menu closes when I click anywhere inside that, even inside a form element. I know it's supposed to do that (or at least it's ok) when there are only links to click on but in my case I need to actually do more than one stuff in there.

Here's part my menu (with the login form):

```
<li class="dropdown pull loginbox">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle icon-user" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="true"> LOGIN</i></a>

<div class="dropdown-menu">

    <section id="signin_alt" class="authenty signin-alt">
        <div class="section-content">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row" data-animation="fadeInUp">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                            <div class="normal-signin"> 
                                <div class="title">
                                    <h2>Sign In</h2>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-main">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="un-wrap">
                                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="pw-wrap">
                                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" checked>
                                                <label>Remember me</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row top-buffer">
                                            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign In</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>      
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 hidden-xs">
                            <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="sns-signin">
                                <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span>Sign in with Facebook</span></a>
                                <a href="#" class="google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i><span>Sign in with Google+</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row top-buffer bottom-wrap">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
                            <a href="<?php echo $serverUrl; ?>login/index.php" id="forgot_from_2">Forgot your password?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
                            <a href="#signup_wizard" id="signup_from_2">Create an account</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</div>
```

All the tags to make the jQuery work are in line 2 and it works! I just need it to not close the sub-menu when the mouse in over it, even if it's clicking like crazy. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a click event on the element you want and then stopping the Propagation inside the click event.

For Example:-

```
$("#some_id").click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();      
});
```

Comment: Nothing. I've tried every possible combination of tags and nothing happens. I can see the stopPropagation on keydown when inspecting the element but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The Div, in which you have your form having following code which may closing your div. Also all of this code should be in li tag followed by ul wnder which you should keep your form.

```
<div class="row" data-animation="fadeInUp">
```